# How can I reset redux state when hitting go back in a web browser?

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

This is my use case:

In the WelcomeScreen I have code like this:

```
class WelcomeScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      checkoutState,
    } = this.props;

    if (checkoutState.status === TRYING_TO_BUY) {
      return this.renderPurchaseForm(plan);
    }

    return this.renderWelcome();
  }
```

When the user visit `/welcome`, he can hit a purchase button, which will dispatch an action and set the `checkoutState.status` to `TRYING_TO_BUY`. The `Welcome` will be rerendered by calling `renderPurchaseForm`

Within `renderPurchaseForm`, it will render a `ArticlePurchaseBlock`

```
  renderPurchaseForm() {
    const { articleId } = this.props;
    return (
    <ArticlePurchaseBlock
       articleId={articleId}
    /> 
    )
```

and in the block, the class will try to update the url to reflect that it is in an input form

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class ArticlePurchaseBlock extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    const { history } = this.props;
    history.push(URL_BUY_ARTICLE);
  }

    render() {
    // render a redux-form
    }
}
export default withRouter(ArticlePurchaseBlock);
```

You can see the `history.push(URL_BUY_ARTICLE);` is called in `componentWillMount`.

**Now the problem is:** when the user in the purchase form, if a user wants to go back to previous url (`/welcome`) , he can't. It is because the state of `checkoutState.status` is still `TRYING_TO_BUY`. The welcome is always rendered to the form.

Is there any where within the `ArticlePurchaseBlock` I can monitor the go back event and unset the state? I do not plan to use `redux-saga-router` yet because of time constraint.

I am using `react-router` v4

Answer (score 1):

I designed a router for this exact problem. It's excessively difficult with react-router.  https://github.com/cellog/react-redux-saga-router.  For your code:

https://gist.github.com/cellog/0731f7e1ba8f9009f6b208c2bd15aa16

The entire thing can be done in 1 line of code, and your routes look almost identical to react-router, with 1 additional line for mapping param or url change to action.